# How to install PHP 5.3 on RHEL5

Tags: php

I'm working with a RHEL5.1 box that has PHP 5.1.6 installed by default. I need to upgrade PHP to PHP 5.3.x.

Comment: 3.x? Do you mean 5.3.x?

Comment: Yes, sorry, edited my question to fix the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. add a repo sourse that support php-5.3 you can see this link to know how to install a repo http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en
2. [root@redhat~]# yum update php php-*
3. you also can compile php5.3 from sourse

Comment: Chosen as answer because, unfortunately, I am stuck on RHEL 5.1

Answer (score 2):

Remove your php* packages and install the corresponding php53* packages -- they've been in the channels since RHEL 5.4. You might need to add the RHEL 5 Server Optional sub-channel to your server's entitlement, if it's not already there.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm on RHEL 5.1. How else can I get the php53 packages?